# New head of marketing department makes no decisions, has no clue of the market, steals ideas

Tags: communication, unprofessional-behavior

I'm working as a webdeveloper for a tire wholesaler and OEM wheel producing company (s/w Germany).

Together with my dear collegues of the marketing department (8) we are facing an awkward problem with our new head of department. Let's call him Tony.

The situation:

Since January 2018 we do have a new head of department.

**The person has a background as a professional cook (!) and gastronomer**, he then somehow made his way into a household company (vacuumer, microwave ofen etc.), then he was head of marketing at a big German beer manufacturer **and has now ended up in our department, being the head of marketing for our company.**

Besides that, he is a professional sportsman, who has attended a couple of sport world cups in the past. One might think that this kind of professionalism enables him to be a good leader. He's not! In other words - you don't have to be smart in order to be sportive.

To give you the crucial points right away:

1. he doesn't make **any** decision
2. he actively steals ideas and sells them as his'
3. he is just a Buzzword-Browser

He is one of those marketing bla bla guys, who can say a thousand words, without making any sense of it, leaving you annoyed after half an hour with an empty head of - sorry - just BS.

The general situation in our company is difficult, because **our company leader/boss/CEO is a very self-confident person**, questioning everything (like leaders, bosses are..) **but** has no technical clue at all - so he is an easy victim when our new head of department, who is more or less fooling him with stolen ideas and stuff.

**1)**
Our biggest problem is that he omits/pivots almost every decision he has to make, simply passing the responsability to us, or keeps sitting on the case and sees what happens. When asked about a certain decision he had to take in, he is flabbergasted and/or forgot it in most cases. Starting his bla bla.. why this and why that was the reason he couldn't get it.

**2)**
Another collegue has been working within the company for over 10 years, he knows what's going on. **Tony took my collegues ideas** and sold them as his' in front of our CEO.

He didn't even put the efford in to change some words or hide the fact, that the idea was stolen - he simply sells it as his'.
When approached about this, he plays the stupid (*uh, really, I'm sorry, didn't know...*).

**3)**
*We have to steer this campaign correctly* **or** *I'm fine with this* **or** *We need to pick our customers up*

All these empty marketing phrases are being said by him day in and day out and every one with just a little sense of **reality** sees, that this guy is an absolute fool and haymaker.

When talking to him, he is litterally just "browsing with you for buzzwords" until he finds a point of interest and then keeps circleing around it.

The problem: Our CEO won't see that he is a clown and - so far - believes his hot air.

Currently "Tony" is untouchable, because of the reasons written above (world class swimmer must be good :eyerolling: ...

**Our problem:**
We really need to get rid of him, he is an absolute clown and overpaid.

**What shall we do? How can we achieve this?**

Thanks for your thoughts, it is much appreciated.

Comment: So feed him some "crap" ideas... I have done this before... works a treat and serves them right for stealing. Of course, the CEO may know already and is only keeping them for the "face"...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like that approach.

Comment: Ugly, but unfortunately good, way is to set him for failure. CYA with an email asking him to make a decision. When he don't make one, don't remind him, don't rush to save the day. Let it crumble. Timestamp al your proposition, presentations, etc. As we call it, hands in your own pockets.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me/us into a direction. We will consider doing so. Thanks for your proposal.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without reasoning, that solves our problem.

Comment: There's a lot of advice on the site about how to deal with such parasites. Taking them on is never fun, and rarely easy; you may end up painting a target on your back, and more than one hard worker has ended up discredited, or fired based on the slander of a character such as your marketing manager.

Comment: The problem with planting bad ideas, or trying to trap him in a missed decision, is that such people are often master manipulators who will have no difficulty turning those things against you. "How can I get rid of my terrible boss?" rarely has a straightforward or easy answer, which is why one of the most common reasons for leaving a job is "I didn't like my boss."

Comment: @user3135691 I upvoted the question as I think it is justified - nonetheless, no reason to be sarcastic to the downvoters. Many people do not like negative (i.e. destructive) advice requests (i.e. "how to take down XYZ"), even if, as in your case, this appears justified. Unfortunately "taking down" can be used against different people, and some of the strategies to take down people work as well (and probably even better) for taking down a capable person who has encountered the ire of their envious colleagues/competitors/bosses as for a hot-air balloon of a boss.

Answer (score 4):

> Our problem: We really need to get rid of him, he is an absolute clown
>   and overpaid.
>
> What shall we do?

You are a developer. Presumably the head of marketing doesn't work for you. As such you should do your job - develop web sites.

If you really feel compelled you could bring your concerns up with the head of marketing's boss. Expect negative push back.

> How can we achieve this?

Talk to the boss. Then go back to developing.

Alternatively, start looking for a new job.

Comment: Really, when does a developer have to interface with the head of marketing? And a web dev at that? OP, a valuable lesson to take in would be "not my circus, not my monkeys." This guys behavior doesn't affect your work. Inserting yourself into others' drama is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I am a developer and I often have to. He will come in and talk to us about what is possible, how to prioritize tasks based on customer demands and generally look through features we add, to see if they solve the issues our customers have.